# Change INPUT with SELECT

Tags: jquery

I was wondering of a quick way possibly using jQuery of changing an INPUT's value using SELECT.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bind an event handler to the `<select>` which will assign the selected value as the input's value:

```
$("#theSelect").change(function() {
    $("#someInput").val($(this).val());
});
```

Depending on your specific requirements, you may or may not need to trigger the handler once on page load (*will need* if the input is to be set to the initially selected option).

```
$("#theSelect").change(function() {
    $("#someInput").val($(this).val());
}).change(); // trigger once if needed
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/BXu26/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $('input').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean set the value of a text box to the value of a drop down list when it is changed?  Do that like this:

```
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
    $("#myInput").val($(this).val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="demoInput" /> 

<select id="demoSelect" />
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>


$('#demoSelect').change(function(){
    $('#demoInput').val($(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_prasad/7GUaq/